# Is it possible to use a C# lambda expression to create an instance of System.Linq.Expressions.Expression at compile time?

Tags: c#

A C# lambda expression (of type [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1)) in code:

```
Expression<Func<Something, bool>> predicate = s => s.SomeProperty == 12;
```

To create a similar instance of [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Something), "s");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(Something).GetProperty("SomeProperty"));
var constant = Expression.Constant(12);
var expression = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
```

Is there a way to declare `expression` given only the `predicate`? So without building the expression tree step by step in code, but having the compiler infer it from a lambda expression.

```
var expression = Expression.FromLambda<Something>(s => s.SomeProperty == 12);
```

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: `predicate.Body`?

Comment: It's the body of the lambda, right?

Comment: Now you just need to finish off the expression

Comment: Isn't that what you have done on line 1, declare it? The first line is an instance of expression. You can use it like any other built expression. Try `predicate.Compile()` When you wrap a Func in Expression, it is implicitly an instance of Expression.

Comment: `public static Expression FromLambda<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func) => func.Body;`? I know you're saying "compile time", but the compiler also just generates code for the expression tree, so... (More generally, `FromLambda<T,U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> func) => func.Body;`, invoke as `.FromLambda((Something s) => s.SomeProperty == 12);`.)

Comment: Can I ask what it is you are ultimately trying to achieve here? You want to be able to use `var`? is that it?

Comment: Indeed; in your question, you get a BinaryExpression from the result, but if you want to make this generic, you are going to lose even that, just getting an Expression from your FromLambda. That seems much less useful than your input Expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just grab the body of the lambda expression, like so:

```
Expression FromLambda(Expression<Func<Something, bool>> lambda)
{
  return lambda.Body;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var expression = FromLambda(s => s.SomeProperty == 12);
```

Comment: result of the cast will be null. You are very close though. Just return the lambda and your done.

Comment: Have you run this code? How do you expect to cast the body of type `Expression.Equal` into `Expression<Func<...>>` ? That's not going to work is it?

Comment: Thank you for the comments; indeed I had the return type incorrect. Now it is the same result as in the original question.

Comment: Sorry about the down vote.  Rereading the question, you did answer it as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the expression

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> FromLambda<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda) {
    return lambda;
}
```

And use as desired

```
var expression = FromLambda<Something>(s => s.SomeProperty == 12);
```

This however is not very flexible and targets just this scenario. You would need to create methods for any other delegate you want to use.